# How to install Java from official site java.com?

Tags: software-installation, java

I've seen this question before but the answer is usually
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`
`sudo apt-get install default-jdk`
or there is no answer.

The software I am using requires official java from official site java.com. Openjdk, default-8-jre, etc. always returns error when trying to start a program but I am having difficulties installing java from java.com:
https://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp

Software provider said I should install this version
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64rpm_install.xml
however I am using Ubuntu based distro so I think I would need this instead
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml

I have troubles installing this version since in step 3 it says

`When the installation has completed, you will see the word Done.`

I never see the word "Done". Needless to say, installation guide on java.com is lacking information which is why I'm here.

So I would like to request a step by step guide how to install official Java from java.com without leaving steps (and assuming I know something I don't; I need to point out I am not a pro linux user). For both versions, just in case... And I would also like to request a guide to uninstall all traces of said installation in case there is a need to do it again in the future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Comment: I will try this out. Even if it does I would still like the answer to my question since I am having the exact same problem every time I make a fresh linux installation or need to solve a different problem and there is suddently a new, uncompatible, version of Java.

Comment: You're right: RPM is the version for distros which use RPM packages, e.g., RedHat, CentOS, and Fedora, so you would not use https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64rpm_install.xml . There is a way to convert and RPM package to DEB for Ubuntu, if you ever need; see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/alien.1p.html

Comment: Have you tried https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml  It is for tgz files.

Answer (score 1):

I use a package named `update-sun-java` for this purpose.  It is distributed through a ppa (I'm not at home, so don't have my repository list available now; I'll try to update this later), so some might consider this excessively risky, but I've been using it this way for several years.  This ppa maintainer obtains the Java runtime and other packages direct from Oracle/Sun/whoever, and packages them in a .deb.

I find I usually have a one or two day delay after a new update drops from the originator before the ppa makes an update available.  Browsers don't use this much any more, but I still use Java software locally on my computer, so I keep this ppa active on my system.

In searching for the PPA name I use, I found there is now a group called LinuxUprising who are doing the same job, possibly having taken over from the maintainer I'm used to.  Their `ppa:linuxuprising/java` isn't familiar to me, but Google brings it up when I try to search for the one I'm used to.

Comment: For what it's worth, I use a couple of `linuxuprising` ppas, with good results.